# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1. Python requests

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests

I am going to get my data but I am getting errors as indicated on the title. I am requesting a post with no data but with parameters in url

here is my code

```
def post_and_get_id(self):
    url = 'https://heremyurl_post'
    data = {
        'last_name': self.last_name,
        'first_name': self.first_name,
        'is_admin': self.is_admin,
        'is_active': True
    }
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % self.authentication(), 'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    payload = json.dumps(data)
    request = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    response = request.json()
    return response['id']

def get_client(self):
    id = self.post_and_get_id()
    url = f'https://my_url_get_data?id={id}'
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % self.authentication(), 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    request = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
    print(request.content)
    return request.json()
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 70, in <module>
    print(object.get_client())
  File "main.py", line 66, in get_client
    return request.json()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 910, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

here are my steps first I am posting a data to URL to get id and with that id, I can get data by post requests. Unfortunately, it is not working `self.authentication()` is a method for token. Everything is working except `get_client()` method . Please can anyone help me? Any help would be appreciated!

**PS**

With that ID I posted in the postman it worked but in my code not (

Comment: what is the response code itself? maybe `403` ? check with add a User-Agent!

Comment: I debugged in pycharm it shows all data in protected variables but how can I visualize it?

Comment: `print(request)` !

Comment: it return only status code 202: <Response [202]>

Comment: so you don't have a valid response! `print(request.text)`!

Comment: if I print text it return empty string

Comment: are you calling an API ?

Comment: yes of course  .

Comment: change `True` to empty str `""` or `true`

Comment: in postman it works as expected

Comment: did you included the `User-Agent` ?

Comment: no why should I include?

Comment: postman by default include a `User-Agent`!

Comment: just a sec now gonna include

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235002/discussion-between--c-and-coder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, within first function you've to return the Auth token which you used.

You don't need to recall it from second function as it's will generate a new one.